# Sharing internal traffic filter across GA4 properties

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I manage multiple websites for a large multi-national (dozens of offices around the world, each with its own set of IP addresses).  I'm in the process of migrating from the old UA to the new GA4. Currently all my properties have filters applied to filter out internal traffic and traffic from our external monitoring service. These together are comprised by several hundred IP addresses and ranges.  Presently I'm using regex filters and I can define filters on account level and then apply them to multiple properties.

With GA4, I can configure internal traffic on the stream level - which means I'll have to configure it separately for each individual property, listing all of these hundreds of IP ranges.  Leaving aside the question of whether GA4 stream filter even supports that many IP ranges, is there a way to define this list once and then apply it to multiple streams?

Comment: I don't believe you can define the list once and apply to multiple streams. The only upside is GA has regex on the IP filter. With your situation, I don't think that helps too much. It may be worth contacting GA through their help center. Many times they anticipant issues like yours and are working on a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In GA4, you can't directly apply internal traffic configurations across multiple streams. However, you can simplify the process by:

1. Creating a central document listing all IP addresses.
2. Making a template stream configuration with internal traffic
   filters.
3. Copying IP addresses from the document and pasting them into each
   stream's settings.

This manual process ensures consistency but can be time-consuming. Check for future GA4 updates for improved management options.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I was forced to do.  But with dozens of IP subnets applied to dozens of properties - we are talking hours if not days of manual copying/pasting. It beggars belief that Google wouldn't foresee this.

Comment: Google Analytics 4 (GA4) requires configuring internal traffic settings separately for each stream within a property. There is no built-in feature to define a single list of IP ranges and apply it to multiple streams. To get the most up-to-date information, check the latest GA4 documentation or contact Google Analytics support, as they may have introduced new features or changes since then.